# WooCommerce Subscriptions - Replace Sign up button with custom field url if user have active subcription

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I build a learning website by wordpress + woocommerce + woocommerce subcription + advanced custom field. The idea is create a simple subcription product, then if anyone bought subcription they will see the Enter Class button instead of Sign Up button.

I did google for help and try some code but no luck. Please help me. Thank you so much!

```
function has_active_subscription( $user_id=null ) {
    // When a $user_id is not specified, get the current user Id
    if( null == $user_id && is_user_logged_in() ) 
        $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    // User not logged in we return false
    if( $user_id == 0 ) 
        return false;

    global $wpdb;

    // Get all active subscriptions count for a user ID
    $count_subscriptions = $wpdb->get_var( "
        SELECT count(p.ID)
        FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts as p
        JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta as pm 
            ON p.ID = pm.post_id
        WHERE p.post_type = 'shop_subscription' 
        AND p.post_status = 'wc-active'
        AND pm.meta_key = '_customer_user' 
        AND pm.meta_value > 0
        AND pm.meta_value = '$user_id'
    " );

    return $count_subscriptions == 0 ? false : true;
}
// Shop and archives - Replace add to cart ajax button to a custom linked button
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'replace_loop_add_to_cart', 20, 2 );
function replace_loop_add_to_cart( $html, $product ) {
    if( has_active_subscription( $product->get_id() ) ) {
        $link = get_field('link_enter_class');
        $text = __("Enter Class", "woocommerce");
        $html = '<a href="' . $link . '" class="button alt add_to_cart_button enter_class_button">' . $text . '</a>';
    }
        return $html;
}

// Single products: Replacing the button add to cart by a custom button on single product pages
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'replace_single_add_to_cart_button', 1 );
function replace_single_add_to_cart_button() {
    global $product;

    if( has_active_subscription( $product->get_id() ) ) {
        // For variable product types (keeping attribute select fields)
        if( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
            remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_variation', 'woocommerce_single_variation_add_to_cart_button', 20 );
            add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'custom_single_add_to_cart_button', 20 );
        }
        // For all other product types
        else {
            remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
            add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'custom_single_add_to_cart_button', 30 );
        }
    }
}

// Utility function: displays a custom  button replacement
function custom_single_add_to_cart_button() {
    $link = get_field('link_enter_class');
    $text = __("Enter Class", "woocommerce");
    echo '<a href="' . $link . '" class="button alt add_to_cart_button enter_class_button">' . $text . '</a>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The **wcs_place_subscription_order_text** filter can be used to customize the button.

```
function custom_filter_wcs_place_subscription_order_text( $button_text ) {
    $button_text =  __( 'Enter class', 'woocommerce-subscriptions' );
    return $button_text;
}
add_filter( 'wcs_place_subscription_order_text', 'custom_filter_wcs_place_subscription_order_text' );
```

Instead of adding the link on the button, On the success page, you can redirect the user to that link.

```
function redirect_to_class( $order_id ) {
    $link = get_field('link_enter_class');
    wp_redirect( $link );
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'redirect_to_class', 1 );
```